# HighCharts / Highstock How to build 100% stacked area chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Is it possible to accomplish a 100% stacked area chart in High Charts or High Stock?  This chart will need to display data over time and each date must added up to 100%.  I have tried building an Highstock area chart but it is really is not what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out you can add the following to the chart's plot options

```
plotOptions: { area: { stacking: 'percent'} }
```